# PHP/MySQL change one drop down menu on the selection of another

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want second drop down list to appear on the selection of the first one (chain the 2 selects). How to do that if any one can guide me or give me an illustration, I'll appreciate that!

**First drop down:**

```
<select name="customer">
   <option value="">--</option>
     <?php
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY customer ORDER BY customer";
       $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
          while ($cust = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
            echo "<option value='".$cust["customer"]."'".($cust["customer"]==$_REQUEST["customer"] ? " selected" : "").">".$cust["customer"]."</option>"; } ?>
</select>
```

**Second drop down:**

```
<select name="product">
   <option value="">--</option>
     <?php
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY product ORDER BY product";
       $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
            echo "<option value='".$row["product"]."'".($row["product"]==$_REQUEST["product"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["product"]."</option>"; } ?>
</select>
```

[image: Table Structure]

Comment: Use ajax. while populating the second select box check if the first select box have any option or not.

Comment: you can look at this nice [blog](http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/5568/creating-dependent-dropdown-list-php-jquery-and-ajax.html)

Comment: Do you want just to make the 2nd select visible (look @Jenz) or do you want to chain the 2 selects. E.g. too have the values of the product to depend on the values of the customer?

Comment: @tliokos i want to chain the 2 selects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First drop down:

```
<select name="customer" onchange="this.form.submit()">
   <option value="">--</option>
     <?php
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY customer ORDER BY customer";
       $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
          while ($cust = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
            echo "<option value='".$cust["customer"]."'".($cust["customer"]==$_REQUEST["customer"] ? " selected" : "").">".$cust["customer"]."</option>"; } ?>
</select>
```

#### Second drop down:

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['customer'])){ ?>
<select name="product">
   <option value="">--</option>
     <?php
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE customer = ".$_REQUEST['customer']." GROUP BY product ORDER BY product";
       $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
            echo "<option value='".$row["product"]."'".($row["product"]==$_REQUEST["product"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["product"]."</option>"; } ?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

you may add a where condition into second drop-down ,query will be,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE customer = ".$_REQUEST['customer']." GROUP BY product ORDER BY product";
```

combined code:

```
<form name="demo" action="#">
     <select name="customer" onchange="this.form.submit()">
       <option value="">--</option>
         <?php
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY customer ORDER BY customer";
           $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
              while ($cust = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$cust["customer"]."'".($cust["customer"]==$_REQUEST["customer"] ? " selected" : "").">".$cust["customer"]."</option>"; } ?>
    </select>

    <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['customer'])){ ?>
    <select name="product">
       <option value="">--</option>
         <?php
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE customer = ".$_REQUEST['customer']." GROUP BY product ORDER BY product";
           $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row["product"]."'".($row["product"]==$_REQUEST["product"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["product"]."</option>"; } ?>
    </select>
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: could you please provide some other solution as it is giving error due to -- WHERE customer = ".$_REQUEST['customer']." --

Comment: which error you have arise and if possible then show a data_table column and demo data of it.

Comment: OK, I edit my answer see this ...i check if 1 is selected then 2 will display then you don’t have any error.

Comment: onchange="this.form.submit()" where is this java-script function ?

Comment: using this form will submitted page itself.

Comment: Ajay! i updated the code accordingly but when i select the customer onchange="this.form.submit()" is called and page doesn't load properly.

Comment: thanks ajay! it worked i took $cust = $_REQUEST["customer"]; and then used it in query WHERE customer = '$cust'

Answer (score 0):

Make the second drop down as disabled on page load like :

```
<select name="product" style="display:none;" id="product">
  .........
</select>
```

and `onchange` event of first dropdown write the following function :

```
<select name="customer" onchange="showdrop()" id="customer">
.....
</select>
```

Use the following code for jquery function for showing the second dropdown :

```
<script>
function showdrop()
{
     var customer=$("#customer").val();   // get the value of currently selected customer
     $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    dataType:"text",
    data:"customer="+customer,
    url:"products.php",         // page to which the ajax request is passed
    success:function(response)
    {
             $("#product").html(response);   // set the result to product dropdown
     $("#product").show();
    }
})


}
</script>
```

and create a php file products.php and write the query for getting the products corresponding to customer (can change according to yours) in it and return the dropdown from there.

```
   <?php
    $customer=$_POST['customer'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." where customer='$customer'";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) 
    {
                echo "<option value='".$row["product"]."'".($row["product"]==$_REQUEST["product"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["product"]."</option>"; 
    } 
    exit;
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Jenz! But, what i want is to populate the second drop down on the basis of selection of first drop down from mysql.

Comment: For that you need ajax..How you are populating the dropdown ? On what basis

Comment: i am populating the dropdown from mysql database table, both the columns (customer & product) are in same table.

Comment: I mean you want to show the product drop down according to the value of drop down 1 no?? what is the connection between these two??

Comment: I want to show the products having selected customer. For example product = WFST having customer = MBAt

Comment: okay..so you want to show the products corresponding to the selected customer..can you show me the table structure..

Comment: You can remove the code for config.php from the question. Anyway it is not needed.

Comment: Jenz please see the image above for table structure.

Comment: did you included js library in your file

Comment: Jenz could you please share your email id, so that i can send you the files to view them and guide me accordingly.

Comment: if not add this to the <head> section of your view page  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: after this also if it is not working, then try to alert something inside js function and check whether you are getting the selected customer value in that..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#customer").change(function(){

$("#product").show();

});
```

Or add option to second one on change **Dynamically**

```
$("#customer").change(function(){

//get dynamically option for product by ajax or array
    var customer = $("#product");
    $('<option>', { 
             value: "example",
             text: "example"
        }).appendTo(customer);

    });
```

## [Checkout Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7W9bv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach below if you want to use pure javascript.

In addition to the other jquery answers, you need to check if the customer is not empty because you need to hide the product element in case the user selects the empty option again.

Update your select element to call the javascript function.

```
<select name="customer" id="customer" onchange="showProducts()"></select>
```

Hide the product select by default.

```
<select name="product" id="product" style="display: none">
```

Create the javascript function.

```
<script>
function showProducts() {

    var customer = document.getElementById('customer').options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var product  = document.getElementById('product');

    if (customer != '')
        product.style.display = 'block';
    else
        product.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```